# Why are restriction enzymes not frozen?

Tags: molecular-biology, enzymes, proteins

We all know restriction enzymes are proteins, but we never freeze them. They are instead provided in high glycerol containing solutions by companies and stored at -20C. Is there a reason why this is so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just so much more convenient to have the enzymes ready without having to thaw them. The main reason you freeze enzymes is to keep them active, if you figure out a buffer that keeps them unfrozen without compromising activity, that is a huge increase in convenience.

Not having to thaw the enzymes before use saves a lot of time, if you can manage to keep the enzymes active in those non-freezing conditions that is a clear advantage.

Glycerol also [stabilizes proteins in solution](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19817484), and multiple freeze and thaw cycles can negatively affect enzyme activity for some enzymes.

Comment: Just as an addition: you can do the same with antibodies. On reception, dilute them 1:2 in glycerol and you can avoid aliquoting them and don't have to worry about freezing cycles (remember to double the amount when you use them, though)!

Comment: Glycerol is added as an anti-freeze agent as well, so that the enzyme can be kept at low temperature (low kinetic energy) and therefore stay stable for longer periods of time.

Answer (score 5):

Freeze-thaw cycles denature proteins through local pH change effects

Comment: A little brief? :)

Comment: It does get the point across.